# Sliding bar calculator?

Tags: math, slider, rating

This website, http://www.ukgoldrefiners.co.uk/ under the top right window "HOW MUCH IS GOLD WORTH?" there are three sliders that estimate what the current gold price is. Its obvious it uses a formula that multiplies the weight of gold by the current gold price (taken from and external source) of the various carats.

If I manipulate this for my own project :-
I have three or more sliders and I can select a value between 1 to 100 and the live number is an average of all the numbers on the slider. e.g

Rating 1:  1-------|--100 (70)
Rating 2:  1-------|--100 (70)
Rating 3:  1-------|--100 (70)

So the average would be 70 and if I manipulate the slider it would change the average number.

My question would be what would this be called? What would I use to make this, JQuery, Java, HTML? Is there any resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) for an excellent jQuery slider. I've used it before and it includes lots of functionality for event functions such as `change` which you can use to do your calculation.

Your html would look something like:

```
<div id="slider1"></div>
<div id="slider2"></div>
<div id="slider3"></div>
<div id="average"></div>
```

And you would initialize each of the slider div's with something like this:

```
$("#slider?").slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        //average out the values of all 3 and set the value of 'average' to the averages.
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, I am still playing with it ... sorry forgot to mark as answered